# combine two array into json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two arrays like this

```
var labels = [name, address, stuff];
var data = [Jhon, white house, other stuff];
```

they have the same lenght. 
I want to combine them into a json like this:

```
{"name":"Jhon", "address":"white house",.... and so on}
```

so basically one array holds the key and the other the values.
I'using javascript. Is there a way to do that easily?
I read online that I can parse an object into a json but it seems impossible I can't simply combine two arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is to iterate over the arrays and assign to an object via expandos. Since the lengths are the same, you can just use one of the arrays as the length.

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
   obj[labels[i]] = data[i];
}
```

You can then convert this object into JSON via the JSON.stringify() method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
   var asJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: and then i parse that object into a proper json?

Comment: Nice, thank you! I tryed it in my code and the for cicle works perfectly, and it generates a json even without the stringify.

In fact the stringify returns {} for some reason

Comment: it does not work if there is a duplicates in first array, example:

var a = ["a1", "a1", "a3"];

var b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"];

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my favorite features of JS. Indexable objects make some tricky bits of code so powerfull.

```
var newObj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < labels.lenght; i++)
    newObj[ labels[i] ] = data[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj={};
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
     obj[labels[i]]=data[i];
}
```